# update table info in form, when info is entered thru another form

Tags: ms-access

I have an MDE database that's limited, so I made an external database with linked tables to the MDE. (I'm using the MDE for functions & forms that are in the database, as the stuff that's there are very well done, just there I like to enter the info a different way then in the MDE, also I created nicer reports so I use the external database for that).

I enter payments in the old MDE, but I want to print a receipt from the new database, the problem is that I only get the info up to when the form that has the print button was opened, (need to go thru a form as I have a few options, so I need to close the form & reopen, I tried refresh & it didn't help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to _requery_ the form. Refresh is not enough.